# Angular app shows 404 page on aws ec2

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, routes

**EDITED**

I have developed an angular app and integrated REST api developed in golang ( hosted on same aws ec2 instance ). I have a domain on godaddy which is pointed to aws server using ip address ( A record ) and angular app files have been uploaded under var/www/html folder on aws, after uploading app files its not working properly and showing 404 page for all urls except home page, home page loads properly ( may be because of index.html file ) but inner pages shows 404

Following is my htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

REST apis are hosted on same server but on 8080 port and I am accessing angular app directly on domain ( ex. mydevsites.com)

How can I get my app working ?

**OLDER**

I have 2 angular apps, one for customer and second for admin I have uploaded customer app on a subdomain dev.mysite.com and admin app under admin folder on same domain so it should be loaded on dev.mysite.com/admin

first page page loading properly but when I access any other page it gives me 404 error

I have setup `<base href="/">`  in customer app and `<base href="/admin/">` in admin app and following code in htacccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Most of the articles suggest for above solutions which I already have done , not sure what is the issue and how it can be resolved

Answer (score 1):

use `useHash` in your router `RouterModule.forRoot`

```
RouterModule.forRoot(your_router_config, {useHash: true})
```

Comment: I realized that its an AWS issue, same app is working on other hosting like godaddy. Updated my question